# Trying to implement a 2D BST but my add and contains method are not working

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm attempting to implement a kd tree, in the form of a 2D tree, however, my implementation is failing. Essentially, what I'm doing is at each level of the tree, an item is added based on either its x or y coordinate. After one adds the root node, the next node added is compared to the root nodes x coordinate and if it is less, it's placed on the left side of the root node, and if it is greater, on the right side of the root node. The next node after the 2nd node iist then added based on x-coordinate again as like in a BST, a maximum of 2 nodes can only be added per parent. The third node would be compared based on the y-coordinate.

I have made some strides to get my add and search (contains method to work) but to no avail. I have tried doing conditional tests to check whether or not the nodes when added should go on the left hand side of the root or other nodes (if their x-coord is smaller) my add method does not seem to be working. Here is my entire program so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TwoDTree {
    /*************
     * attributes
     ************/

    TwoDTreeNode root;

    /***************
     * constructor
     **************/
    TwoDTree() {
        root = null;

    }

    /**********
     * methods
     *********/
    /**
     * To Do: adds a new node with the given x and y coordinates to the TwoDTree
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     */
    public void add(int x, int y) {

        TwoDTreeNode currentNode = root;
        TwoDTreeNode previousNode = null;
        TwoDTreeNode newNode = new TwoDTreeNode(x,y);
        boolean useXCoordinate = false;
        boolean useLeftSubTree = false;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            useLeftSubTree = useXCoordinate ? (newNode.xCoordinate < currentNode.xCoordinate) : (newNode.yCoordinate < currentNode.yCoordinate);
            useXCoordinate = !useXCoordinate;
        }

        if (root == null) {
            root = new TwoDTreeNode(x, y);
        } else if (useLeftSubTree) {
            previousNode.left = new TwoDTreeNode(x,y);
        } else {
            previousNode.right =new TwoDTreeNode(x,y);
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @returns true if a node with the given x and y coordinates exist in the
     *          tree.
     */
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {

        TwoDTreeNode currentNode = root;
        TwoDTreeNode newNode = new TwoDTreeNode(x,y);
        boolean useXCoordinate = false;
        boolean useLeftSubTree = false;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            useLeftSubTree = useXCoordinate ? (newNode.xCoordinate < currentNode.xCoordinate) : (newNode.yCoordinate < currentNode.yCoordinate);
            useXCoordinate = !useXCoordinate;

            if ((currentNode.xCoordinate == newNode.xCoordinate) && (currentNode.yCoordinate == newNode.yCoordinate)) {
                return true;
            }
        }


        return false;

    }

    /**
     * A method which prints a level order traversal of the tree
     */
    public void levelOrderPrint() {
        Queue<TwoDTreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TwoDTreeNode>();
        queue.add(root);
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            TwoDTreeNode node = queue.poll();
            System.out.print("(" + node.xCoordinate + "," + node.yCoordinate + ")");
            if (node.left != null)
                queue.add(node.left);
            if (node.right != null)
                queue.add(node.right);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Building a tree of nodes: (30,40) (5,25) (10,12) (70,70) (50,30) (35,40)");
        TwoDTree tDTree = new TwoDTree();
        tDTree.add(30, 40);
        tDTree.add(5, 25);
        tDTree.add(10, 12);
        tDTree.add(70, 70);
        tDTree.add(50, 30);
        tDTree.add(35, 40);
        System.out.println("Level order traversal for this tree is:");
        tDTree.levelOrderPrint();
        System.out.println("contains(5,25) returned: " + tDTree.contains(5, 25));
        System.out.println("contains (10,13) returned: " + tDTree.contains(10, 13));
        System.out.println("contains (35,45) returned: " + tDTree.contains(35, 45));
    }


    private static class TwoDTreeNode {
        /*************
         * attributes
         ************/
        int xCoordinate;
        int yCoordinate;
        TwoDTreeNode right;
        TwoDTreeNode left;

        /***************
         * constructors
         **************/
        TwoDTreeNode(int x, int y) {
            xCoordinate = x;
            yCoordinate = y;
        }

        TwoDTreeNode(int x, int y, TwoDTreeNode leftChild, TwoDTreeNode rightChild) {
            xCoordinate = x;
            yCoordinate = y;
            left = leftChild;
            right = rightChild;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `newNode` in the add method?

Comment: Where I wrote previousNode.left/right = new TwoDTreeNode(x,y), I had substituted that for newNode, and it did not work